# What is the difference between using getUrl() and getUrlPath() in Magento?

Tags: category, geturl

What is the difference between using getUrl() and getUrlPath()?

In the following code

```
$_brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

foreach($brand as $brandid)
{       
    $_brands->load($brandid);               
    echo '<span class="row-set-'.$count.'"><a href="'.$_brands->getUrl().'"><img src="'.$_brands->getImageUrl().'"/></a></span>';                                                   
}

foreach($sub as $subkey => $subid)
{                               
    if($subkey%2!=0){ $classid='"sub-odd'; }else { $classid='"sub-even';}
    $subcat->load($subid);      
    echo '<li class='.$classid.' hell"><a href="'.$subcat->getUrl().'">'.$subcat->getName().'</a></li>';

}
```

Using the brand ids and subcat ids that are stored separately I am retrieving the url using getUrl() but for every brands and subcategory always the first brand and subcategory fetched is repated for other brand ids and subcat ids as well. But the getName() and getImageUrl() are working perfectly.

When I changed the getUrl() to getUrlPath() everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the full URL is not stored in the database, but generated from base URL and path, and Magento is smart enough to only calculate derived attributes once per model, then cache them internally. Unfortunately you are using the same model instance `$subcat` for each category and just reload different data, so you get the first cached value every time. It probably helps to clear it before reloading:

```
$subcat->clearInstance()
```

But I would not recommend this at all. I don't know, where your arrays `$brand` and `$sub` come from, but you should change them into a collection so that all categories are loaded at once and not in a loop. Your current code is a performance desaster.

Answer (score 1):

getUrl will generate a fully formed URL, i.e. with the http(s):// and domain, whereas getUrlPath returns just the 'path', i.e. the part after the domain name.

Comment: Why does the problem in the above scenario happen?

Answer (score 0):

getUrl() give category url with full format-`SiteUrlBaseUrl+urlKey+urlsuffix`..

**UrlKey:** UrlKey is `category  Eav Attribute field`.

if a Categoru Url_Key is `test` and site url  http://www.test.com and theN

getUrl() is  `http://www.test.com/test.html` here category html suffix is `.html`
then url path is `test.html`